# do I need to change the default database prefix?

Tags: wordpress

When do one needs to change the default database prefix OTHER THAN SECURITY REASONS?

Let's not worry about securities, so is there any performance concerns?

See I have four or more WordPress site on one server(not multiple sites), like:

http://www.12reads.cn/

http://www.12reads.cn/wiki/

http://news.12reads.cn/

http://peixun.12reads.cn/

All of them are using WordPress and sharing a same database prefix.

Is there any problems for that when it comes to site performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using for just your website Secure that mean no one hacks your website 
If you comfortable with your security then no need to change the prefix.
The main purpose of changing prefix to Secure your website from hackers.
You can change the wp-admin folder slug.

For more details please check this URL

https://www.wpwhitesecurity.com/wordpress-security/change-wordpress-database-prefix/

Comment: Thank you .But say I will use memcache ,will the same prefix still no worry?

Comment: No, suppose you have installed WordPress with your prefix wp_ then you have installed a plugin with name event manager then plugin prefix will take place into database after WordPress prefix like wp_em_events, and the WordPress default tables prefix remains same wp_